# How to express "either the single resulting record or NULL", without an inner-query LIMIT?

Tags: sql, syntax, window-functions, monetdb, inner-query

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT (SELECT MIN(col1) FROM table1) = 7;
```

Assuming `col1` is non-NULLable, this will yield either true or false - or possibly NULL when `table1` is empty;

But now suppose I have:

```
SELECT (
  SELECT 
    FIRST_VALUE (col2) OVER (
        ORDER BY col1
    ) AS col2_for_first_col1
  FROM table1
) = 7;
```

(and assume `col2` is also non-NULLable for simplicity.)

If there is a unique `col2` value for the lowest `col1` value, or the table is empty, then this works just like before. But if there are *multiple* `col2` values for the lowest `col1`, I'm going to get a query runtime error.

My question: What is a short, elegant way to get `NULL` from this last query also in the case of multiple inner-query results? I could of course duplicate it and check the count, but I would rather avoid that.

Important caveat: I'm using MonetDB, and it doesn't seem to support `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1` on inner queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the MonetDB limitation, you would seem to want:

```
SELECT (SELECT col2
        FROM table1
        ORDER BY col1
        LIMIT 1
       ) = 7;
```

with the limitation, you can use window functions differently:

```
SELECT (SELECT col2
        FROM (SELECT col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) as seqnum
              FROM table1
             ) t
        WHERE seqnum = 1
       ) = 7;
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I should have mentioned that's impossible for me to do. See edit.

Comment: what if you put the subquery in a `with ... as` clause?

Comment: @einpoklum . . . Odd limitation.  I actually needed to check the MonetDB documentation to verify that `LIMIT` is the right syntax.  Alas, I didn't check if it could be used in subqueries.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I guess there's nothing yet another level of inner querying can't solve :-P